# How does bcrypt know which hashed method has been used

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

I have a key which is salted and hashed using SHA-256. if I use bcrypt for compare this, Dose bcrypt know which hashing method has been using for hash the key. Or I need to define the method in somewhere.

```
bcrypt.compare("string","base256-hashed-and-salted-key", function(err, res) {
   // res == true
});
```

Comment: You can only use `bcrypt.compare` if the hash was originally calculated with `bcrypt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter is the string you're wanting to check (e.g. password from a login form). The second parameter is the hash value you got as a result of `bcrypt.hash()` that you retrieve from a database or some other data store.

bcrypt does not care if the string you hash is pre-hashed with SHA-256 or if it's just the plain text password itself. bcrypt hashes any kind of data.